# VB.NET: AccessVilolationException was unhandled in OleDB

Tags: vb.net

This error is new to me. It says Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

and this error is pointed in this block of codes:

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + textSelectFiles.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "]", cn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
```

Am I missing something or what? 
Thanks in advance with your suggestion and tips.

Comment: That error message comes from a much lower level than that code and doesn't really tell you what went wrong.  The first thing to do whenever you get an exception is to look at ALL the information available.  The Exception Assistant window has a View Details link for a reason.  One important piece of information is the stack trace.  Having said all that, have you actually looked at your connection string and your SQL query to make sure that they are exactly what you expect? I'm guessing probably not. When things go wrong, ALWAYS confirm that you're using the data you think you are.

Comment: I assume ComboBox1 is filled with the sheet names from the selected file. Yes? I had some odd behavior with that provider. 32 bit vs, 64 bit. I switched to the 64 bit and unchecked prefer 32 in Application properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
Dim constr As String
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim sda As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim row As DataRow

Try
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtOpen.Text + ";Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"
    con = New OleDbConnection(constr)
    sda = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + cboSheet.SelectedValue + "]", con)
    dt = New DataTable
    sda.Fill(dt)

    For Each row In dt.Rows
        DataGridView3.DataSource = dt

    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I hope it will works!

Comment: Why are you setting the DataSource property dt.Rows.Count times is your For Each loop? It only needs to be set once.

Comment: It works, and I see the difference and problem. Thanks!